# When I do "uuidgen" in Unix how does it generate the ID?

Tags: unix, uuid

When I do "uuidgen" in Unix how does it generate the ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uuidgen` comes from libuuid, which is part of [e2fsprogs](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/)

The manual page for the e2fsprogs uuid_generate functtion states:

> The  uuid  will be generated based on high-quality randomness
>   from  /dev/urandom, if available. If it is not available, then
>   uuid_generate will use an alternative algorithm which uses the
>   current time, the local ethernet MAC address (if available), and random 
>   data generated using a pseudo-random generator.